# Yeoman prompt never exits

Tags: mingw, yeoman, yeoman-generator, mingw-w64

I am brand new to `yeoman` generators (I've used plenty of 3rd party generators just never wrote my own)...

Whenever I ask a question to the user with a prompt, the process never exits:

```
var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  // The name `constructor` is important here
  constructor: function () {
    // Calling the super constructor is important so our generator is correctly set up
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

    // Next, add your custom code
    this.option('coffee'); // This method adds support for a `--coffee` flag
    this.log('Your first generator');
  },
    prompting: {
        askForInsightOptIn: function () {
            var done = this.async();
            this.prompt({
                type: 'confirm',
                name: 'insight',
                message: 'How are you?',
                default: true
            }, function (prompt) {
                done();
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
});
```

The console output looks like:

```
$ yo debug-test
Your first generator
? How are you? (Y/n) y
? How are you? Yes

I can type anything here and it never responds

waiting...
```

If I comment-out the code for the prompt, everything works as expected.

```
$ yo debug-test
Your first generator

$
```

**Why would adding a prompt prevent the generator from exiting gracefully?  Am I missing something in the generator that is not closing the async correctly?**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "generator-debug-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "files": [
    "app",
    "router"
  ],
  "keywords": ["yeoman-generator"],
  "dependencies": {
    "yeoman-generator": "^0.20.2"
  }
}
```

---

**Looks like this is a problem with MINGW64 bash I was using.** If I switch over to the native windows command prompt, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js support for command line is a bit flakey, especially for windows. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5384

Issues with using readline related modules on any prompts should be reported on the Node.js bug tracker as that's a framework support issue.